# Firefox dismisses the alert and throws alert not found exception

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

**When i click acceptInvite( i am expecting an alert to accept) but Firefox closes the alert quickly and my code throws no alert found exception.
(Note: Switching to a frame to click acceptInvite and expecting the alert box to stay in the page until i accept the alert)

Version 
Selenium webdriver 3.141.0 
Selenium.Firefox.wedDriver 0.24.0
Firefox 63.0.3**

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("open")).click();  (Navigates to next page)
Driver.SwitchToFrame(0); 
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("acceptInvite")).click();
Driver.SwitchToDefaultContent();
//Accept alert 
try
{
    var alert = Driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
    if (alert != null)
    {
        var alertText = alert.Text;
        Log.setTestDebug("ALERT TEXT IS " + alertText);
        alert.Accept();
    }
}
catch (NoAlertPresentException e)
{
    throw e;
}

//Fire fox options
var options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.UnexpectedAlertBehavior, "ignore", true);
Driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```